# Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FF923531470 (vcruntime140.dll) в CV.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа п чтении по адресу 0x00000082AFD001EF

Tags: c++, opencv

Начинаю работать с OpenCV, и оно сразу бьет меня исключением указанным в заголовке. Всё что я написал привожу ниже.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
using namespace cv;


int main() {
    Mat img = imread("lalala.jpeg");
    
}
```

Comment: Стек вызовов при падении еще стоило бы привести.